# Posting comments that contains javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-3

I am building an website that will  have possibility to add comments on news .
And I am not sure how to prevent users from posting comments like:

```
<script>
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        alert("Tes");
    });
</script>
```

For building website I am using MVC3.

My question is :
What kind of threads may exist in this case?
What are all the possibilities to insert a comment like this ?

Comment: asp.net mvc should automatically html encode content for you, unless you use `@Html.Raw()`. If you want to allow some html, but not all, that's a much more complicated topic.

Comment: Is this 100% secure ?

Comment: I don't think you can call anything 100% secure. But as far as I know, the mvc framework properly encodes html output.

Comment: Yes I know but I don't know all possibilities to do this .This is I was asking about it.
First I want to find best possibilities and then test it to mvc.

Comment: If you're asking about all the of the ways to avoid an xss filter, this is a good list: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet

Comment: The default html encode is a blacklist.  Try using Microsoft AntiXss Project instead.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to prevent this is to HTML encode the output being displayed on the screen.  This will prevent any markup or scripts from being displayed or executed and is a fundamental of preventing cross site scripting attacks.

The main threat that is present by allowing script or markup to be injected into your page via a user comment is cross site scripting.  Cross site scripting attacks commonly inject additional markup into the page.  This markup often will pass a user's cookies such as the session id to an attackers server.  At this point the attacker can use the session id to hijack the users session.

Another attack with cross site scripting is to install a keylogger on the client that passes the text the user enters to a rogue server allowing the attacker to obtain information such as the users credentials.

Comment: I more interested in " What are all the possibilities to insert a comment like this ?"

Comment: What do you mean by the possibilities?

Comment: Thanks, but what about second question?

Comment: I mean if is any possibilities at all  to do this ,any trick ?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer I will search for "Cross site scripting " sound interesting...

Answer (score 0):

Throwing some more info into the mix.

XSS attack prevention is the term to search on.

Manually you can search and remove all offenders before you "save" with lines like -

eg.

```
  bloginput = bloginput.replace(/<script/g, '');
```

!Which you would also do on the server.

A utility which I like is - https://github.com/chriso/validator.js

Top and bottom of it is, treat your blog entry like a 'string' and strip out those which pose a threat before you allow a save to your database or access to your deeper server code.

Comment: This isn't 100% reliable. I've seen vulnerabilities where an attacker puts some characters in the script tag that prevent it from matching regexes, but that the browser will ignore (so the script gets executed).

Comment: Sure thing Jason, just trying to show the basic idea, and hope I pointed out that any string sanitisation/rules would ALSO need to be set in the server side code.

Comment: Should have said "This isn't 100% reliable _by itself_." Definitely nothing wrong with trying to clean out some junk up front.